# How can I continuously measure mobile network coverage on a particular journey?

Tags: networking, 3g

Every day I spend almost 2 hours on a train to my job and back. My current cellular provider gives me a terrible service most of the time within the train. I'd like to buy/borrow SIM cards of all available providers and measure the network performance while I'm traveling, and then compare the results afterwards to see which one performed best.

How can I record and compare the network coverage on a journey like this?